# Why does my code not write to my file path indicated in write to CSV?

Tags: python, operating-system, cwd

I have a dataframe. I want to write it to a csv in a specific path. I attempted-

```
import os
df3
out_path =  ('//gg-data-share/jobs/Compliance')

df3.to_csv(out_path + 'CombinedEscalations.csv')
```

the script runs successfully, however, it writes to `//gg-data-share/jobs` instead of within the `Compliance` folder and weirdly it saves the file with a different name:

`'ComplianceCombinedEscalations.csv'` in the jobs folder instead of the subfolder.

Am I doing something wrong in `out_path`?

Comment: `'//gg-data-share/jobs/Compliance' + 'CombinedEscalations.csv' = '//gg-data-share/jobs/ComplianceCombinedEscalations.csv'` Put a `/` between them.

Comment: No, **don't** manually concatenate them like that, use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an issue in the way you are adding the two strings together in your `to_csv()` argument.

When you add your strings together, you get a result as demonstrated below.

```py
string_1 = '//gg-data-share/jobs/Compliance'
string_2 = 'CombinedEscalations.csv'
string_sum = string_1 + string_2

string_sum

# Result
'//gg-data-share/jobs/ComplianceCombinedEscalations.csv'
```

This is because adding strings has no regard for the format in which you created the strings in the first place. Thus, you need to make sure that when you add them together you preserve any file-structure formatting you intended.

To have your DataFrame saved to a `Compliance` subfolder with the name `CombinedEscalations.csv`, try the following.

```
out_path =  '//gg-data-share/jobs/Compliance' # this is a folder

df3.to_csv(out_path + '/CombinedEscalations.csv') # add a '/'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why os.path.join() is safer?

Comment: Platform independence. On Windows/mac/Linux you use `/`  or \ ; `os.path.join` takes care of this

Comment: @DinoThunder My answer is really only for your isolated use-case in which you're running your script locally using local directories. `os.path.join()` is intelligent, handles drive letters, and works with path-like objects which makes it a priceless tool when writing cross-compatible code or even deployment code. If you're just writing casual local scripts, there's nothing wrong with the above method.

Comment: my script will run on another server and will run on a schedule. How would you use os.path.join() in my case?

Comment: Use `os.path.join(path_name, file_name)` substituting your directory and the target CSV file name. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) documentation for more on it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `/` after Compliance. Also I recommend

```
import os
os.path.join(path_name, file_name)
```

help to be platform independent (although you would have to specify the path differently on a different platform)

Comment: Thank you. marking preritdas answer correct cause it came before.